# WordPress - How to use PHP inside HTML injecting function?

Tags: php, wordpress

I have a function that injects HTML code, the function looks like this:

```
function page_content() {
     echo <<<HTML
         <body>
             <?php ?> //this won't work
         </body
         <style>
         </style>
     HTML;
 }
```

Is there any way to write PHP code inside this HTML injection function?
This function is used for replacing the default WP Dashboard, but writing just HTML and CSS is limiting me totally :( Thanks

**edit:**

I have resolve this by breaking the HTML into two parts like this:

```
    function page_content() {
    echo <<<HTML
        <body>
            <div class="test">
                <p>Body</p>
                <p>Body</p>
                <p>Body</p>
        HTML;
    echo do_shortcode('[contact-form-7 id="86" title="My Form"]');
    echo <<<HTML
                <p>Body</p>
                <p>Body</p>
                <p>Body</p>
            </div>
        </body>
        <style>
            .test {
                display: flex;
                flex-direction: column;
            }
        </style>
    HTML;
}
```

If there is any better or easier way of doing this please let me know. I'm only learning, so always happy to learn the best ways of solving things in PHP. Thanks guys!

Answer (score -1):

You can write like this.

```
<?php 
function page_content() {
    $output = 'HTML
         <body>';
    $output .= write php code here;
    $output .=' </body
         <style>
         </style>
     HTML';

     echo output;
 }
 ?>
```

I wrote like this so that you can understand easily but if you get used to combining HTML with php, you can just write together using .' and '. lol

```
<?php 
function page_content() {

    $output =
    'HTML
         <body>' . $write_anything_with_php .' </body>
         <style>
         </style>
     HTML';

     echo output;
 }
 ?>
```

Comment: Thank you for your time but unfortunately this doesn't work. But I have done this in simpler way, not too sure if the correct way but it works. BTW I didn't downvoted you someone else did same as my post. I have added my way under my post.